# android button - Pressed button should be in Magenta Color

Tags: android, button

Its regarding Color of the Button. I am Designing calculator to learn Android and features of Button.

```
 Button Lastbutton = null;
```

Lastbutton i created for storing the previously pressed values. So first time it is null.

```
 if ( Lastbutton == null )
 {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " First TimeAnswer As of Now : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    Lastbutton = buttonToAdd; ( buttonToAdd is the button object pressed)   
 } 
 else
 {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " second TimeAnswer As of Now : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
 ---  Some calculation ----
    Lastbutton = buttonToAdd; ( buttonToAdd is the button object pressed)       

 }
```

In the If (LastButton == Null) is failing. How to identify that button has not stored any value.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what your problem is and post your full onClick(?) method, please.

Comment: where u have initilised Lat Button..if it is in xml than use findViewById before using.